# github.worspace is not returning the right path

Tags: azure, github, terraform, github-actions, devops

I'm currently working on a terraform form and github actions where is connected to my Azure instance.

My current main.yml file is set up like this:

```
name: 'Terraform'

on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
  pull_request:

env:
      TF_VERSION: latest
      ARM_CLIENT_ID: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_ID }}
      ARM_CLIENT_SECRET: ${{ secrets.CLIENT_SECRET }}
      ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
      ARM_TENANT_ID: ${{ secrets.TENANT_ID }}
      ROOT_PATH: '${{ github.workspace }}/src/terraform'

jobs:
  terraform:
    name: 'Terraform'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: dev

    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Directory Path
        run: |
          ls -la

      - name: Terraform Init
        uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
        # run: |
        #   cd src
        #   cd terraform
        #   terraform init
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.TF_VERSION }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'init'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.ROOT_PATH }}
          tf_actions_comment: true
        env: 
          TF_VAR_env: 'dev'
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Terraform Format
        uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.TF_VERSION }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'fmt'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.ROOT_PATH }}

      - name: Terraform Plan
        uses: hashicorp/terraform-github-actions@master
        with:
          tf_actions_version: ${{ env.TF_VERSION }}
          tf_actions_subcommand: 'plan'
          tf_actions_working_dir: ${{ env.ROOT_PATH }}
```

At the time I see the directory path, I found out that is outside of my working directory. Then, further steps are going to tell me that I don't have any configuration.

Do you know if `ROOT_PATH: '${{ github.workspace }}/src/terraform` needs to be setup differently? or What else can I do to make sure I'll have the root directory which is src/terraform?

Comment: What does `ROOT_PATH` actually represent? After checkout, the current path will be inside your repo directory. Is that different than `ROOT_PATH`?

Comment: You have to tell each step where to get the path from. So, that's why I created an env variable to make sure it can help me to find it quicker